# Magento: set config values of just created website?

Tags: web, magento, initialization, config

I'm programmtically creating websites/users etc ...

Here's the problem: When creating a website, I can't immediatly set the config values afterwards.

Code:

```
<?php
/* Website information */
$website_data = array(
            'name' => 'Company name',
            'code' => 'website_company_1',
            'sort_order' => '1',
            );

/* Save website */
$website = Mage::getModel('core/website'); 
$website->setData($website_data);
$website->save();

/* Get website code */
$web_code = $website->getCode();

/* R-int stores */
Mage::app()->reinitStores();

/* Config data array example */
$data = array('name' => 'Company 1', 'phone' => '056 22 33 61')

/* Set config values in array */
$groups = array();
 foreach($data as $key => $value){
 $groups['store_information']['fields'][$key]['value'] = $value;
 }


/* Save config values */
Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
      ->setSection('general')
      ->setWebsite($web_code)
      ->setStore(NULL)
      ->setGroups($groups)
      ->save();


/* Re-init again */
Mage::app()->reinitStores();
```

However, this doesn't work for some reason, but if I create a website first(with the same code), then execute this config-save function afterwards, it works fine. As if it needs a new page load first before it can set/update config values. I thought the re-init would solve this but it doesn't ...

Thoughts?

Comment: Additional details would help people debug this.   Specifically, what's in $website_data and $data, and where are they getting populated from.

Comment: Added some example code, since the actual code is way to much to put here. both are just associative arrays that work fine a website that was already created, just not on on that was created in the same script ...

Comment: I suspect there is some indexing going on here.  Try turning on SQL logging (ref http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/77655/) to trap any indexing or other activity after creating the website, then track down the code that is responsible for it, and replicate it in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't mention which Magento version you are on. I have tested the below on 1.4.1.1 and made some changes so it is a running example.

The main difference is the change from

```
Mage::app()->reinitStores();
```

to

```
Mage::app()->getConfig()->reinit();
```

which re-loads the config while also reloading the cache.

**Complete Example:**

```
<?php

require_once 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Mage.php';
Mage::app();

/* Website information */
$website_data = array(
    'name' => 'Website Name',
    'code' => 'website_company',
    'sort_order' => '2',
    'is_active' => 1,
);

/* Save website */
$website = Mage::getModel('core/website');
$website->setData($website_data);
$website->save()->load();

/* Save store */
$storeGroup = Mage::getModel('core/store_group');
$storeGroup->setData(
        array(
            'root_category_id' => '3',
            'website_id' => $website->getId(),
            'name' => 'Store',
        )
);
$storeGroup->save()->load();

$store = Mage::getModel('core/store');
$store->setData(
        array(
            'website_id' => $website->getId(),
            'name' => $storeGroup->getName(),
            'code' => 'store_' . $website->load()->getId(),
            'group_id' => $storeGroup->getGroupId(),
            'is_active' => 1,
        )
);
$store->save()->load();

/* Re-init */
Mage::app()->getConfig()->reinit();

/* Config data array example */
$data = array('name' => 'Company 1', 'phone' => '056 22 33 61');

/* Set config values in array */
$groups = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $groups['store_information']['fields'][$key]['value'] = $value;
}

/* Save config values */
$data = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
                ->setSection('general')
                ->setWebsite($website->getCode())
                ->setGroups($groups)
                ->save();
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to set secure and unsecure base link url for a store programmatically?

Answer (score 7):

You should use install/upgrade scripts for this purpose (these are the scripts inside modules' **sql** folders). You may even wish to create a setup-specific module with/in which to run these.

Simply declare a setup resource in your module's global/resources node and then create the file(s) you need to accomplish this. Use **[Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.5/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php)** or have your setup class extend from there.

See **Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::*setConfigData()*** and **Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::*deleteConfigData()***.

Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::*addConfigField()* could also be used but is not implemented in the core from what I can tell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- module config.xml -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <!-- upgrade script #s evaluated with version_compare(), FYI -->
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <unique_node>
                <setup>
                    <!-- match node under <modules> -->
                    <module>Your_Module</module>
                    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </unique_node>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then in your install/upgrade scripts do this:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */ //or whatever you configured

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->setConfigData($path, $value, $scope='default', $scopeId=0) //inherit is not implemented

$installer->endSetup();
```