# How to create a site,store and view programmatically in magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to create a website, store and view programmatically. I found this code:

```
$websiteModel = Mage::getModel('core/website');

$postData = array();
$postData['website']['name'] = 'Store Name';
$postData['website']['code'] = 'store_name';
$postData['website']['sort_order'] = '';
//$postData['website']['is_default'] = '';
$postData['website']['website_id'] = '';

$websiteModel->setData($postData['website']);
```

Would something like that work? Also what would be the models associated with store and view?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use this code:

```
//#addWebsite
    /** @var $website Mage_Core_Model_Website */
    $website = Mage::getModel('core/website');
    $website->setCode('<your_website_code_here>')
        ->setName('<your_website_name>')
        ->save();

//#addStoreGroup
    /** @var $storeGroup Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group */
    $storeGroup = Mage::getModel('core/store_group');
    $storeGroup->setWebsiteId($website->getId())
        ->setName('<your_store_name>')
        ->setRootCategoryId('<needed_root_category_id>')
        ->save();

//#addStore
    /** @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
    $store = Mage::getModel('core/store');
    $store->setCode('<your_store_view_code_here>')
        ->setWebsiteId($storeGroup->getWebsiteId())
        ->setGroupId($storeGroup->getId())
        ->setName('<your_store_view_name>')
        ->setIsActive(1)
        ->save();
```

If you need do it from frontend - add line `Mage::registry('isSecureArea');` before this code.

Comment: Thanks, that worked wonderfully well. Could you tell me how do i set the base url for a particular website? Thanks again.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601643/magento-set-config-values-of-just-created-website) helped me in setting the config values for the website created.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I have only one question. How it should be? Just mysql upgrade or another way?

Comment: Just a question. When creating the storegroup for the new website, I must define a root category id. So should I create the new category before creating the new storegroup?

Comment: @DarkCowboy, You can choose to add a new root category before you create the storegroup or you can set it to an already existing root catagory. Just check in your script that the root category exists before trying to use it.

Comment: @Oleg, using a setup script (install/upgrade) is the best way for most situations. This way Magento will keep track for you if the script has been executed on the database or not. Of course, depending on you use case, you may find a different approve more suites your needs. In that case, did what works best for the give situation.

Comment: @Zavya - do you have idea about same code for magento 2 ?