# magento apis for creating websites, store, and storeview

Tags: magento

I cannot find the Magento apis for creating websites, store, and storeview in Magento by using Soap.

Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 2):

It is not in the API!

In code you can do it if you follow the answer on this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8313029/1617149

Of course you can extend the API:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api

...and write your own module that does what you need.

Good luck!