# how to create the store or store view in magento using the script

Tags: magento

I'd like to create a new store or store view in `Magento`.
Can any one suggest me how to do it without using `Magento admin Gui`?
Means to create store using the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look better, first hit while googling "magento create store programmatically":

[How to create a site,store and view programatically in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309076/how-to-create-a-site-store-and-view-)
programatically-in-magento

There is your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Magento API with [SOAP](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) or [API REST](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html).